# Session variables are not working in chrome

Tags: google-chrome, session, payment-gateway

I have checked through many process but still there is a problem.

I am creating a session variable and it is working fine in all the pages, but when I am trying to pass the `session["amt"]` to payment gateway **its not working** ***only in chrome***, *but its working fine in Mozilla and IE*.

Can any one please suggest me where am I doing mistake?

Comment: creating session variable in php?

Comment: No, creating in C# .net

Comment: sorry i m not familiar with c#.net. only thing i can say that session is handled on server side and it should not effected on browser. only thing is dependent that is "cookie".

Comment: using different approach to prevent timeout in Chrome's session. [link](https://weblogs.asp.net/stevewellens/ah-ah-ah-ah-staying-alive-staying-alive)

Answer (score 0):

Disable all Chrome Extensions. Close your Chrome browser. (Mac Os X: Stop Chrome with CMD+Q) Then try again. If the problem is solved: turn on your Chrome Extensions one by one to detect the conflicting extension(s).