# Automatic session expired in google chrome

Tags: c#, asp.net, google-chrome, session

I am storing login user information into session at login time
with below code :

```
Session["LoginUserId"] = txtUserName.Text;
```

When I am running an application in google chrome my session will be automatically null after a few minutes, but for Mozila Firefox and internet explorer it is working Fine.

And I have set expire time for seesionState but it is also not working.

So, Please suggest me what can I do?

Comment: Does https://forums.asp.net/t/1552666.aspx?Session+variable+value+lost+in+Chrome+but+works+fine+in+IE+FF+ help? Or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14747256/session-variables-are-not-working-in-chrome ?

Comment: Can you give us any more context about the website? Is it a 'normal' website? A facebook app? Something else?

Comment: @mjwills
It is normal Project management website and i  have already try your both question link but that not work for me

Comment: Have you tried disabling all add-ons in Chrome?

Comment: @ Mad Myche yes i have tried but it's not working

Comment: Use a clock or stopwatch, and detemine exactly how long it takes for the session to stop working (1 minute? 5 minutes? etc), and then please let us know.

Comment: @mjwills I have check but every time  session will expire on  different timing 2min, 3min, 5min or 1 min

Comment: using different approach to prevent timeout in Chrome's session. https://weblogs.asp.net/stevewellens/ah-ah-ah-ah-staying-alive-staying-alive

Answer (score 1):

Store session table instead of browser Session and check session and expired time every time of login and user activity.

You can manage session by increase logout/expire time, it will help you to increase session time.

Comment: That should be a comment instead an answer, please see [Help-Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) for better answer! it's not good to give answer before really understand under laying problem, SO is different then nopCommerce forum :)